# Filling a dictionary with lists of values - why is my nested loop only running once?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary, quantile, binning

I'm trying to create a function that takes an array, bins the data in that array (by quantile), and fills a dictionary with the binned data. In the dictionary that gets produced, I want the keys to correspond to bin numbers, and the values to be lists of data from the input array that fall within the jth and (j+1)th bin limits.

Here is my code:

```
output = []
def binning(array1):
    d1 = {} # empty dictionary to fill with lists of values
    bin_edges = sp.stats.mstats.mquantiles(array1, prob=[0.0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875,1.00])
    j = 0   
    while j < len(bin_edges):
        for i in range(0, len(array1)): 
            if float(array1[i]) > bin_edges[j] and float(array1[i]) <= bin_edges[j+1]:
                output.append(array1[i])                

            d1["bin_number{0}".format(j)]= output
        j+=1
        return d1
```

The problem is, the inner loop only runs once, so I'm getting an output like

```
d1 = {'bin_number0': [value1, value2, etc.]}.
```

What I want to see is:

```
d1 = {'bin_number0': [value1, value2, etc.],'bin_number1': [value3, value4, etc.],'bin_number2': [value5, value6, etc.]}
```

...and so on, so there are 8 keys corresponding to 8 lists of values.

Can anyone tell me why the inner loop only runs once (for j = 0)? I've looked at it so many times I need a fresh pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

`return d1` should not be indented into the while loop. Unindent it so that it is indented only once. This is why your code only loops once. Hope this helps!!